# Angular 4 ngFor on typescript indexer

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface defined in typescript:

```
interface MethodMappings {
    [name: string]: {
        methodMappings: ClassMethodMappings[];
    }
}
```

with a local variable

```
public classMappings: MethodMappings;
```

How do I use e.g. ngFor to iterate through an object of this type? If I just use for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let m of classMappings"></div>
```

I get the error:

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I understand that an indexer is not an array but is there an Angular iterator I can use over the indexer?

Comment: Not yet. Use Object.entries() and transform your object to an array.

Comment: Seems to be the answer but cannot get this to work. I've added "es2017.object" and "es2016.array.include" into tsconfig.json. Oddly I can do 'Object.entries(classMappings) in the debugger, but it fails when in the typescript file.

Comment: *es2017.object* only provides the type definitions for *Object.entries*, if your environment does not have an *Object.entries* implementation, you will need a **polyfill** such as *core-js*.